# Show how many characters there are in each element in an array (based on scanner input)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

This is an assignment for school that I've been trying for way too long. I know how to print the total character count (as seen in the code). For example, entering `Joe` and `Jane` would result in `[7]`. How can I make it print `[3, 4]` or how long each name is?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the length of the array:");
    int length = s.nextInt();
    String[] myArray = new String[length];
    String input; 
    int allChar = 0;
           
    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array:");

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        myArray[i] = s.next();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
     
    input = Arrays.toString(myArray);
      
    for (int charCount = 0; charCount < input.length(); charCount++) {
        if (Character.isLetter(input.charAt(charCount))) {
            allChar++;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Total Characters: " + allChar);
}
```

Comment: ``` input = Arrays.toString(myArray);`` will gives  add the following characters [ ] and , to input.  That means your string will be a lot longer than the actual length of the name entered.  Why not each the length of each string in the array and and total them up?

Comment: This is just a ridiculous question to be honest.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

> *How can I make it print [3, 4] or how long each name is?*

You could create an array of integers to store the lengths of the names `int[] nameLengths = new int[length];` and then fill this array according to your requirements (using `String::length()` or counting only letters in each name) *along* with incrementing the total `allChars`.

Then print the contents of `nameLengths` array using `Arrays.toString`.